# React intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I simply can't get React.js IntelliSense to work in Visual Studio code.

I have done the following:

- `npm install typings`
- `ext install Typings Installer` in Visual Studio Code
- `ext install Typings` in Visual Studio Code
- `typings init` in the root directory of my "app"
- `typings install --ambient react-global` in the root of my "app"
- restarted Visual Studio Code

That's created a `typings` folder. My app is structured in the following folder structure:

```
├───public
│   ├───css
│   └───scripts
|       └───test.js
└───typings
    ├───browser
    │   └───ambient
    │       └───react-global
    └───main
        └───ambient
            └───react-global
```

Yet when I'm in `test.js` and type `React.` I get no IntelliSense.

I presume I'm missing something fundamental?

EDIT: Thanks for your help, it's actually more involved again. I *think* I have it working and wrote about my steps here https://mattdufeu.co.uk/blog/setup-intellisense-vscode-react-js/

Comment: Sorry I don't know the cause of this.. luckily React core has like 4 functions :) and most projects only use two or three at most.

Comment: Check the console (Help > Toggle Developer Tools) - Visual Studio Code crashes pretty frequently, the Javascript engine might have crashed. I wouldn't suggest using VSCode for Javascript editing, at least for a few months until the bugs are ironed out.

Comment: do you see salsa at the bottom right? if it has an exclamation point - it means the most recent version of salsa isn't being supported, make sure to install the most recent release of typescript as typescript@next

Comment: @AndyRay nothing in the developer tools.

Comment: @gabdallah I didn't even see salsa as an option. Thank you

Comment: The link to http://mattdufeu.co.uk/setup-intellisense-vscode-react-js/ appears to be broken.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to add jsconfig.json to the root of your workspace

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

[Note: you can even leave the `jsconfig.json` file empty]

Comment: This certainly did something, not quite sure it was what I was expecting, but it did help. I'll tick this as it seemed to make the biggest difference

Comment: Is it possible to get intellisense for react lifecycle methods as well?

Comment: 2019: Just solved same issue for me.  I've been using `yarn build`, but IDK if that has anything to do with it.  Can anyone explain _why_ this works?

Answer (score 14):

Now that typings (and for that matter tsd) are both no longer recommended.  I found the one line answer for my situation was just to include type definitions from npm with the command

`npm i @types/react --save-dev`

intellisense picked up the new definitions for me immediately in Visual Studio Code, but perhaps for someone else you may need to restart your VSCode window.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but my app was created with create-react-app with the latest version.

Comment: This actually worked in VsCode. I was testing inside a text/babel block though and could not make this work. But moving back to a .js file, your answer helped me get Intellisens of React and ReactDOM members. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else encounters this question in March or April 2016, you might also wish to check this issue in github to see if it has been closed:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/61

Essentially, using `import React, { Component } from 'react'` ES6-style module import causes Salsa's Intellisense not to work, the workaround is to use require:
`var React = require('react'); var { Component } = React;`

Answer (score 4):

If you add an empty **jsconfig.json** file to your react project it will crash the build process.
just fill it with something like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe also add `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this working, with go to definition and all working with react jsx.
You need jsconfig.json, looking like this (note you *need* the "jsx": "react" property, and to specify the trailing 'index.jsx' in the aliases, if using the implicit class-as-folder-name paradigm):

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": { 
            "shared/*":       ["./components/shared/*/index.jsx"],
            "components/*":   ["./components/*/index.jsx"],
            "stores/*":       ["./lib/stores/*"],
            "services/*":     ["./lib/services/*"],
            "utils/*":        ["./lib/utils/*"]
        },
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

Then imports like this all work:

```
import UserApi from 'services/api/UserApi';
import EditArea from 'components/views/Blog/EditArea';
import EditableLabel from 'shared/EditableLabel';
```

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  }
} works for me!

Answer (score 2):

All I needed to do was to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

#### Reference

- [How to trigger IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features)

Comment: Not quite sure, but I think I had `"editor.quickSuggestions"` set to
`false`, which would explain why I had to hit
`Ctrl` + `space`.
Anyways, I have changed it to `true` for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled ES7+ React extension and closed vs code and opened the project in vscode using the  cmd and suddenly the intellisence start working i hope this will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).