# How to make vs code autocomplete React component's prop types?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsx, javascript-intellisense

How to make VS Code autocomplete React component's prop types while using the component in JSX markup?

P.S.: I'm using JS, not TS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950385/react-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: VS Code has still to update lot more, Webstorm provides this by default.

Comment: this issue recommends a way to do that: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24926#issuecomment-294992766, I'll try to post this as an answer

Comment: if your only purpose is to use React and JS I would advise you to use https://nuclide.io/ with `ATOM`.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703015/exposing-react-component-proptypes

Comment: convert everything to typescript! :D

Comment: If `JSDoc` `@param` is provided you have full autocomplete. Otherwise `TypeScript` is the solution.

Answer (score 12):

There is also option to use @params definition:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {{header: string, subheader: string, imageAlt: string, contentList: Array, orderLink: Object, contentLink: Object}} props 
 */
export default function JumbotronMain(props) {...}
```

[image]

Comment: this does not seem to work with class components ?

Answer (score 8):

I noticed that if you have a stateless component and you get the props using ES6, when you use this component, you get the props with the autocomplete.

```
const Stateless = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 3):

You can also get intellisense support from [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).  You'll need to install [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

```js
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Header(props) {
  return <h1>{props.headerText}</h1>
}

Header.propTypes = {
    headerText: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Header
```

[image: example of intellisense]

Comment: this only seems to work for function components

Comment: I haven't checked but I am sure you can do this using class component by this way.



static propTypes = {
        headerText: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // <-- how can I validate that this is a component class (or stateless functional component)?
    };

Comment: @gaurav5430 no you can implement this on class component as well. 

check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/72983342/6703780

Answer (score 0):

for the class components you can use propTypes to do the job, you can follow this link for details -> [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```