# Exposing React Component PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, npm, components, react-proptypes

I am developing some reusable components in React Native. I have defined some **PropTypes** for components but when I publish the components to my private **npm repository** the Props Intellisense doesn't work.

As an example if I define a **title** **propType**, when I add the component to another component if I start typing **t...** it doesn't suggest **title** to me.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can use augments to do that. Just define your props in the augments part they will appear in the suggestions as you type.

```
/**
* @augments {Component<{ title:string, anotherProp:boolean>}
*/
class MyReactClass extends React.Component {

}
```

If you're using vscode, I've created a simple extension to do that automatically. But it requires you to define propTypes.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cuneyt-aliustaoglu.vscode-react-proptypes-intellisense