# VS Code autocomplete/intellisense not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, frontend

Building my first React project from https://frontendmasters.com/courses/complete-react-v5/ on VS Code for Windows 10.

Have installed prettier, eslint. Using Parcel to transpile the code. The intellisense is only working on index.html file. Nothing on js files. Have looked through old answers and none of them proved to be helpful. A bit of a noob here, a step by step solution will be helpful

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fAQI.png)
Attaching project files

http://www.filedropper.com/adapt-me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950385/react-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 21):

on the right bottom, change the language mode Javascript to Javascript React

[image]

Comment: it helped for me most of the time it happens now found the reason

Comment: This worked and enable emmet autocompletion for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that the file you working on is of `JavaScript React` type, currently with `.js` it is a `JavaScript` file type.

You can see the file type on the bottom `Status Bar`

[image]

Use `Change Language Mode` (through command palette) command to change it manually.

Also, you can provide a config in `settings.json` to associate it with a file name, for example:

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.react.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.stories.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.action.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.reducer.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.styles.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.styles.react.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.styles.jsx": "javascriptreact",
    "*.svg.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact",
    "*.js": "javascriptreact",
    ".stylelintrc": "jsonc"
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried these all. Nothing worked. Even the autocomplete is not. For example, I am forced to type both the opening and closing tags of div

Comment: Its an extension, you don't get it out of the box... you don't write html in react

Comment: Point is none of it is working. I start typing console, it shows nothing

Comment: woah what theme is that?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this photo, head to the settings and search for autocomplete, tick them out and you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me, you're a legend. I thought I exhausted all my options up until this point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the extension of ".jsx" to "Javascript React" in the bottom right corner of VS Code.

Click on `Configure File Association for '.jsx'`:

[image: step1]

Then select `Javascript React`:

[image: step2]

Now the autocomplete will happen like if it was an html file.

Also, make sure to add ".jsx" extension to your files instead of ".js".

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your parcel setup. Can you create a Create React App project template [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) and check if the intellisense still doesn't work with the js files in it.

Another alternative is to upgrade your VS code to the latest version if any update is available or else you can download [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and check if the intellisense works as expected.

One other option is to checkout the code from the commit mentioned at the bottom of [this](https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-react-v5/parcel) page and check if the intellisense works for this code.

Answer (score 0):

If your file extension is like .js, convert it to .jsx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to get auto-complete using fs functions. When I switched from requiring to importing fs, the auto-complete appeared. Don't know if it's relevant though. Just a complete newbie.